# SQL count in multiple rows

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
Select 
    ID, Date, Partner
From 
    Orders
Order By 
    Data Desc
```

Result:

```
ID  Date  Partner
1   27    x
2   16    y
3   06    z
4   04    x
5   02    z
```

How can I use `count(Partner)` to get result like this:

```
ID  Date  Partner  Count
1   27    x        2
2   16    y        1 
3   06    z        2
4   04    x        2
5   02    z        2
```

Comment: What DBMS are yuo using?

Answer (score 2):

For MS SQL you can use [Window function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.120).aspx) COUNT for this:

```
Select 
ID, Date, Partner,
count (*) OVER (PARTITION BY Partner) 
from Orders
ORDER BY Date Desc
```

Answer (score 1):

In most databases, you can use the ANSI standard window fucntions:

```
select o.id, o.date, o.partner,
       count(*) over (partition by partner) as cnt
from orders o;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated sub-query to do the counting:

```
Select 
ID, Date, Partner, (select count(*) from Orders o2
                    where o1.Partner = o2.Partner)
from Orders o1
ORDER BY Data Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
ID, Data, Z.Partner,Cnt
from Orders O
inner join
(select Partner, count(Partner) as cnt
from Orders
group by Partner)Z
on O.Partner = Z.Partner
order by Data desc
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6698f/4 for your undertanding...